# How to split string containing multiple delimeters of each and every line of text file?

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

This is the Input my file contains:

```
50|Hallogen|Mercury|M:4;C:40;A:1
90|Oxygen|Mars|M:10;C:20;A:00
5|Hydrogen|Saturn|M:33;C:00;A:3
```

Now i want to split each and every line of my text file and store in my class file like :

**Expected output**:

```
Planets[0]:
{
   Number:50
   name: Hallogen
   object:Mercury
   proportion[0]:
             {
                 Number:4
             },
    proportion[1]:
             {
                 Number:40
             },
proportion[2]:
             {
                 Number:1
             }
}
```

etc........

My class file to store all this values:

```
public class Planets
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }  //This field points to first cell of every row.output 50,90,5
        public string name { get; set; } //This field points to Second cell of every row.output Hallogen,Oxygen,Hydrogen
        public string object { get; set; } ////This field points to third cell of every row.output Mercury,Mars,Saturn
        public List<proportion> proportion { get; set; } //This will store all proportions with respect to planet object.
         //for Hallogen it will store 4,40,1.Just store number.ignore M,C,A initials.
         //for oxygen it will store 10,20,00.Just store number.ignore M,C,A initials.
    }

    public class proportion
    {
        public int Number { get; set; } 
    }
```

This is what i have done:

```
 List<Planets> Planets = new List<Planets>();
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(args[0]))
                        {
                            String line;
                            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                string[] parts = Regex.Split(line, @"(?<=[|;-])");
                                foreach (var item in parts)
                                {
                                     var Obj = new Planets();//Not getting how to store it but not getting proper output in parts
                                }

                               Console.WriteLine(line);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: What is an example output of parts ? Show us some of the strings that are  in parts.

Comment: Well that looks reasonable. So whats the problem?

Comment: By Hallogen, do you mean *[halogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halogen)* as in fluorine, chlorine, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without you having to change any of your logic in "Planets"-class my fast solution to your problem would look like this:

```
List<Planets> Planets = new List<Planets>();
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(args[0]))
                        {
                            String line;
                            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                Planets planet = new Planets();
                                String[] parts = line.Split('|');
                                planet.Number = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]);
                                planet.name = parts[1];
                                planet.obj = parts[2];

                                String[] smallerParts = parts[3].Split(';');
                                planet.proportion = new List<proportion>();
                                foreach (var item in smallerParts)
                                {
                                    proportion prop = new proportion();
                                    prop.Number =                                    
                                    Convert.ToInt32(item.Split(':')[1]);
                                    planet.proportion.Add(prop);
                                }
                                Planets.Add(planet);
                            }
                        }
```

Oh before i forget it, you should not name your property of class Planets "object" because "object" is a keyword for the base class of everything, use something like "obj", "myObject" ,"planetObject" just not "object" your compiler will tell you the same ;)

Comment: there is a error in your code.Input string was not in a correct format on this line:  prop.Number =Convert.ToInt32(item.Split(':')[0]);

Comment: Yeah your code is working perfectly but consider if my delimeters are not fixed then how would you split and store ?

Comment: Can you give an example of what information would be given about the incoming data ? If we do not know the positions we have to know at least something, for example DataPartA has FormatA and DataPartB has FormatB or DataPartA is of typeA and DataPartB is of formatB or DataPartA has an IdentifierA at its start and DataPartB has an IdentifierB at its start. Some informations are required, if you give me the idea an what you know about the incoming data I will see what I can do.

Comment: Can you please help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32007993/how-to-display-all-data-from-list-object-by-combining-duplicate-data-to-display

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, multiple delimiters are maintained to have a nested structure.

You need to split the whole string first based on pipe, followed by semi colon and lastly by colon.

The order of splitting here is important. I don't think you can have all the tokens at once by splitting with all 3 delimiters.

Comment: If he knows his input always has the same structure that is a possibility, like first splitting newline, then foreach string after this split, split by delimiter, for the 0th, 1st, 2nd, 4th, 5th, 6th, etc you know the type and can move along, for the 3rd, 7th, etc you split again by ; and after each of the last split you build your object with the available data.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code for same kind of data

```
var values = new List<string>
{
     "50|Hallogen|Mercury|M:4;C:40;A:1",
     "90|Oxygen|Mars|M:10;C:20;A:00",
     "5|Hydrogen|Saturn|M:33;C:00;A:3"
};
foreach (var value in values)
{
     var pipeSplitted = value.Split('|');
     var firstNumber = pipeSplitted[0];
     var name = pipeSplitted[1];
     var objectName = pipeSplitted[2];
     var semiSpltted = value.Split(';');
     var secondNumber = semiSpltted[0].Split(':')[1];
     var thirdNumber = semiSpltted[1].Split(':')[1];
     var colenSplitted = value.Split(':');
     var lastNumber = colenSplitted[colenSplitted.Length - 1];
}
```

[image]

Comment: what if my delimeters are not fixed like if i change my first cell delimeter from | to , then

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your input is well formed. In this case you could use something like this:

```
string[] parts = Regex.Split(line, @"[|;-]");
var planet =  new Planets(parts);


...

public Planets(string[] parts) {
    int.TryParse(parts[0], this.Number);
    this.name = parts[1];
    this.object = parts[2];
    this.proportion = new List<proportion>();
    Regex PropRegex = new Regex("\d+");
    for(int i = 3; i < parts.Length; i++){
        Match PropMatch = PropRegex.Match(part[i]);
        if(PropMatch.IsMatch){
            this.proportion.Add(int.Parse(PropMatch.Value));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Error on this line string[] parts = Regex.Split(line, @"([|;-]"); parsing "([|;-]" - Not enough )'s.

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I didn't test the code. It was ment as ilustration. I removed brackets because they are not needed there.

Comment: You shouldnt be thankfull.I should be thankfull to you for your kind efforts towards helping me

Comment: Lots of error is there in your code on following lines:   int.TryParse(parts[0], this.PopulationNumber); Regex PropRegex = new Regex("\d+");

Answer (score 1):

The most straigtforward solution is to use a regex where every (sub)field is matched inside a group

```
var subjectString = @"50|Hallogen|Mercury|M:4;C:40;A:1
90|Oxygen|Mars|M:10;C:20;A:00
5|Hydrogen|Saturn|M:33;C:00;A:3";

    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"^(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|M:(.*?);C:(.*?);A:(.*?)$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    Match match = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
    while (match.Success) {

        match.Groups[1].Value.Dump();
        match.Groups[2].Value.Dump();
        match.Groups[3].Value.Dump();
        match.Groups[4].Value.Dump();
        match.Groups[5].Value.Dump();
        match.Groups[6].Value.Dump();

        match = match.NextMatch();
    }
```