# How to display all data from list object by combining duplicate data to display as a single object?

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting, grouping

This is my input store in file:

```
   50|Carbon|Mercury|M:4;C:40;A:1
    90|Oxygen|Mars|M:10;C:20;A:00
    90|Serium|Jupiter|M:3;C:16;A:45
    85|Hydrogen|Saturn|M:33;C:00;A:3
```

Here **50,90,90,85** indicates **weight** and **M,C,A** represents Proportions in each of this element.

Now i want to display each elements(i.e Carbon,Oxygen etc) **from highest to lowest** and if there are **multiple elements with the same weights**,group them under a single Weight and sort them **alphabetically by Planet**(mars,jupiter) and then **Elements**(carbon,Oxygen etc..)

**Expected output**:

```
1)90 
  Serium;Jupiter (sorted alphabetically by planet name).
  compounds:M:3;C:16;A:45
  Oxygen;Mars
  compounds:M:10;C:20;A:00

2)85
  Hydrogen;Saturn
  M:33;C:00;A:3

3)50
  Carbon;Mercury
  M:4;C:40;A:1
```

This is how i have done:

```
public class Planets
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }  //This field points to first cell of every row.output 50,90,90,85
        public string name { get; set; } //This field points to Second cell of every row.output Hallogen,Oxygen,Hydrogen
        public string object { get; set; } ////This field points to third cell of every row.output Mercury,Mars,Saturn
        public List<proportion> proportion { get; set; } //This will store all proportions with respect to planet object.
         //for Hallogen it will store 4,40,1.Just store number.ignore M,C,A initials.
         //for oxygen it will store 10,20,00.Just store number.ignore M,C,A initials.
    }

    public class proportion
    {
        public int Number { get; set; } 
    }

List<Planets> Planets = new List<Planets>();
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(args[0]))
                        {
                            String line;
                            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                Planets planet = new Planets();
                                String[] parts = line.Split('|');
                                planet.Number = Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]);
                                planet.name = parts[1];
                                planet.obj = parts[2];

                                String[] smallerParts = parts[3].Split(';');
                                planet.proportion = new List<proportion>();
                                foreach (var item in smallerParts)
                                {
                                    proportion prop = new proportion();
                                    prop.Number =                                    
                                    Convert.ToInt32(item.Split(':')[1]);
                                    planet.proportion.Add(prop);
                                }
                                Planets.Add(planet);
                            }
                        }
                     var data = Planets.OrderByDescending(t => t.Number).ToList();//Highest to lowest.
                      foreach (var item in data)
                        {
                            //What to do for same elements
                        }
```

I am successfully able to add all 4 row in my planet list object like this:

```
 Planets[0]:
    {
       Number:50
       name: Carbon
       object:Mercury
       proportion[0]:
                 {
                     Number:4
                 },
        proportion[1]:
                 {
                     Number:40
                 },
    proportion[2]:
                 {
                     Number:1
                 }
    }
Etc.......
```

Here only problem i am getting is for **displaying weight of same number**(**Expected output 1**) and alphabetically sorting by Planet(mars,jupiter) and then by Elements(carbon,Oxygen etc..)

Comment: Is this about displaying or about storing data ? So Planets with the same weight shall be stored stored together in one object or shall any given number of Planets-objects be displayed in the correct order ? If the latter ,how does your displaying-method look like at the moment, please provide code and I will look on how to solve your displaying order issues.

Comment: @MeAndSomeRandoms:It is just about displaying data and not storing data.Planet with the same weight should be combine in to one to display like Mars and jupiter both have same weight so i need to display them in to 1 planet and not different

Comment: So do you want to encapsulate all Planets which have the same weight in another data-structure so that you know inside of this data-structure are all Planets with the same weight in the right order. Or do you want to do the sorting logic when you display the complete list of planets. What I ask is shall the Planets with the same weight be stored together so that you can display them in the right order or doesn't it matter how they are stored as long as the displaying logic orders them correctly. Both is possible.

Comment: @MeAndSomeRandoms:Yes planet with the same weight should be stored together along with the sorting cirteria as i have describe in my question so that i can display them in the right order and it should match my expected ouput.

Comment: A simple groupby on weight shall do the job for you, have you tried using it

Comment: Mybe "ThenBy" could help you to get the order right with ordering by secondary property after the primary property. Example code would be: exampleList.OrderBy(item => item.PrimaryProperty)
            .ThenBy(item=> item.SecondaryProperty).ToList();

Comment: @MeAndSomeRandoms:my main problem is with combining data of same weight.it would be more beteer if you can post your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created the following code on LinqPad to achieve the result that you are expecting, Let me know if you still need changes, a simple Linq query will help in achieving the result:

```
void Main()
{   
    List<Input> customList = Input.Create();

    var result = customList.GroupBy(x=>x.Weight,x=>new {x.Element1,x.Element2,x.Detail})
                       .Select(y=>new {
                                       key = y.Key,
                                       collection = y.OrderBy(z=>z.Element2)
                                      }
                               ).OrderByDescending(h=>h.key);     


    foreach(var n in result)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Weight :: " + n.key);

       foreach(var g in n.collection)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(g.Element1 + ";" + g.Element2);
           Console.WriteLine("Compounds:" + g.Detail);
       }
    }
}

public class Input
{
  public int Weight {get; set;}
  public string Element1 {get; set;}
  public string Element2 {get; set;}
  public string Detail {get; set;}

  public Input(int w, string e1, string e2, string d)
  {
    Weight = w;
    Element1 = e1;
    Element2 = e2;
    Detail = d; 
  }

  public static List<Input> Create()
  {
    List<Input> returnList = new List<Input>();

    returnList.Add(new Input(50,"Carbon","Mercury","M:4;C:40;A:1"));
    returnList.Add(new Input(90,"Oxygen","Mars","M:10;C:20;A:00"));
    returnList.Add(new Input(90,"Serium","Jupiter","M:3;C:16;A:45"));
    returnList.Add(new Input(85,"Hydrogen","Saturn","M:33;C:00;A:3"));

    return (returnList);    
  }
}
```

Comment: Dump method is not coming

Comment: Dump method is not available in linq.

Comment: Edited Dump is a LinqPad method, so will not work here, you can print using a foreach loop and print all the relevant elements, final entity will have two elements, key and collection, where collection itself is an IOrderedEnumerable, it has to be  foreach inside a foreach to print all the details. I have added a code to print, though that will again show everything in separate line, it needs some more logic if you want to avoid reprinting of the weight, using which it is grouped. Essentially inner foreach loop need to verify the value of weight and if its same then avoid printing

Comment: Yeah i have use your code but weight 90 is still printing two times.So how do you avoid that??

Comment: Can you please guide me how do i check this in my inner loop and avoid printing the same value again please>?

Comment: Check it now modified the code to exactly achieve the result you need. If this is fine, then please mark this as an answer

Comment: Thank you.Thank you.thank you so much sir for all your kind help.It really means alot to me otherwise i was feeling really so helpless

Comment: can i ask you for 1 last help?

Comment: Sure but i will respond tomorrow

Comment: Yeah sure.no problem.can you please check this question and help me with it if possible:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043018/how-to-count-occurences-of-number-stored-in-file-containing-multiple-delimeters

Comment: Can you please explain me your query so that i can learn something