# How to count occurences of number stored in file containing multiple delimeters?

Tags: c#, regex, linq, file, collections

This is my input store in file:

```
50|Carbon|Mercury|P:4;P:00;P:1
90|Oxygen|Mars|P:10;P:4;P:00
90|Serium|Jupiter|P:4;P:16;P:10
85|Hydrogen|Saturn|P:00;P:10;P:4
```

Now i will take my first row **P:4** and then next **P:00** and then next like wise and want to count occurence in every other row so **expected output** will be:

> P:4 **3**(found in 2nd row,3rd row,4th row(last cell))
>
> P:00 **2** (found on 2nd row,4th row)
>
> P:1 **0** (no occurences are there so)
>
> P:10  **1**
>
> P:16  **0**

**etc**.....

Like wise i would like to print occurence of each and every proportion.

So far i am successfull in splitting row by row and storing in my class file object like this:

```
public class Planets
    {
       //My rest fields
        public string ProportionConcat { get; set; }
        public List<proportion> proportion { get; set; }
    }

    public class proportion
    {
        public int Number { get; set; } 
    }
```

**I have already filled my planet object like below** and Finally my List of planet object data is like this:

```
List<Planets> Planets = new List<Planets>();
Planets[0]:
    {
       Number:50
       name: Carbon
       object:Mercury
       ProportionConcat:P:4;P:00;P:1
       proportion[0]:
                 {
                     Number:4
                 },
        proportion[1]:
                 {
                     Number:00
                 },
    proportion[2]:
                 {
                     Number:1
                 }
    }
```

**Etc...**

I know i can loop through and perform search and count but then 2 to 3 loops will be required and code will be little messy so i want some better code to perform this.

Now how do i search each and count every other proportion in my planet List object??

Comment: it seems like a home work

Comment: @un-lucky:If you can give me idea too then also it will be fine.I can write logic but then it will be very messy so if i can get a better logic then i can learn so i have ask here

Comment: Can you provide code you did? So, we can make some refactoring and optimization..

Comment: @ArtemKulikov:Actually i am too thinking on that and trying so once if i reach at some point i will update my question with code

Comment: @Learning Can you please specify. You need `expected output` or fill your `planets` structure?

Comment: @ArtemKulikov:I have already filled my planet structure as you can see in my question.Now i just want an expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have parsed proportions, you can create new struct for output data:

```
// Class to storage result
public class Values
{
    public int Count;   // count of proportion entry.
    public readonly HashSet<int> Rows = new HashSet<int>();  //list with rows numbers.

    /// <summary> Add new proportion</summary>
    /// <param name="rowNumber">Number of row, where proportion entries</param>
    public void Increment(int rowNumber)
    {
        ++Count;    // increase count of proportions entries
        Rows.Add(rowNumber);   // add number of row, where proportion entry
    }
}
```

And use this code to fill it. I'm not sure it's "messy" and don't see necessity to complicate the code with LINQ. What do you think about it?

```
   var result = new Dictionary<int, Values>();   // create dictionary, where we will storage our results. keys is proportion. values - information about how often this proportion entries and rows, where this proportion entry
   for (var i = 0; i < Planets.Count; i++)   // we use for instead of foreach for finding row number. i == row number
   {
      var planet = Planets[i];
      foreach (var proportion in planet.proportion)
      {
         if (!result.ContainsKey(proportion.Number))   // if our result dictionary doesn't contain proportion
            result.Add(proportion.Number, new Values());  // we add it to dictionary and initialize our result class for this proportion

         result[proportion.Number].Increment(i);  // increment count of entries and add row number
      }
   }
```

Comment: Getting error on this line:result[proportion.Number].Increment(i);Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Error on this: public readonly HashSet<int> Rows = new HashSet<int>();cannot have instance field initializers in structs

Comment: Yes i have but error is there which i told you in my previous comment

Comment: Well, I added initializator to `Rows` field. Because struct doesn't support it - I changed struct to class. Did you do this? :)

Comment: Yeah now it iw working fine and getting expected output.Thanks for your kind help

Comment: Glad to help you. If it help you - can you please accept the answer?

Comment: Yeah i would sure but just wait let me properly verify and then i will surely accept your answer but your answer in really a sign of genius programmer.I mean really how did you think like that

Comment: Sir can you please put some explaination so that i can learn something from your code

Comment: Sure. I added some comments to answer. hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `var count = Regex.Matches(lineString, input).Count;`. Try this example

```
var list = new List<string>
{
     "50|Carbon|Mercury|P:4;P:00;P:1",
     "90|Oxygen|Mars|P:10;P:4;P:00",
     "90|Serium|Jupiter|P:4;P:16;P:10",
     "85|Hydrogen|Saturn|P:00;P:10;P:4"
};
int totalCount;
var result = CountWords(list, "P:4", out totalCount);
Console.WriteLine("Total Found: {0}", totalCount);
foreach (var foundWords in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(foundWords);
}

public class FoundWords
{
    public string LineNumber { get; set; }
    public int Found { get; set; }
}

private List<FoundWords> CountWords(List<string> words, string input, out int total)
{
    total = 0;
    int[] index = {0};
    var result = new List<FoundWords>();
    foreach (var f in words.Select(word => new FoundWords {Found = Regex.Matches(word, input).Count, LineNumber = "Line Number: " + index[0] + 1}))
    {
        result.Add(f);
        total += f.Found;
        index[0]++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I really really appreciate your efforts for me.thank you so much and please keep helping like this.Your help means alot to novice programmer like me and others

Answer (score 1):

I made a DotNetFiddle for you here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/z9QwmD

```
string raw =
@"50|Carbon|Mercury|P:4;P:00;P:1
90|Oxygen|Mars|P:10;P:4;P:00
90|Serium|Jupiter|P:4;P:16;P:10
85|Hydrogen|Saturn|P:00;P:10;P:4";

string[] splits = raw.Split(
    new string[] { "|", ";", "\n" },
    StringSplitOptions.None
);

foreach (string p in splits.Where(s => s.ToUpper().StartsWith(("P:"))).Distinct())
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        string.Format("{0} - {1}",
            p,
            splits.Count(s => s.ToUpper() == p.ToUpper())
        )
    );
}
```

Basically, you can use `.Split` to split on multiple delimiters at once, it's pretty straightforward. After that, everything is gravy :).

Obviously my code simply outputs the results to the console, but that part is fairly easy to change. Let me know if there's anything you didn't understand.

Comment: I really really appreciate your efforts for me.thank you so much and please keep helping like this.Your help means alot to novice programmer like me and others

Comment: :). Always happy to help.